# Print a List of Arrays in Perl?

Tags: arrays, perl, list, loops

I am attempting write code that will allow me to print a list of arrays in Perl.

I have a list of arrays of GPS coordinates called `@points` that is formatted with arrays of lat/lon like so:

```
@points = [34.2,17.5],[-64.1, 110.35],[54.8,77.1], and so on and so forth
```

I am able to print the list itself using `print "$_\n" for @points;`, however this only gives me the memory reference for the array. I know that you can't just print arrays like you can strings or integers however I am stuck on how to actually iterate through the list and print the integers. I tried using a foreach loop and @_ to print at each increment however that didn't work for me either. If anyone is able to give me any direction on this it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you just use Data Dumper?

Comment: Primarily because I want to be able to know how to do it myself in order to make myself a better programmer, but also because this code will be run as a plugin to a government application that only supports a very old version of perl (don't ask, it doesn't make any sense) and I have had issues in the past using libraries not in the core perl distribution.

Comment: `say "@$_" for @points;`

Comment: @XeroG Data::Dumper was first released with Perl 5.005 in 1998. You must be using a very old version of Perl, indeed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing two dimensional iteration so you need a two dimensional loop. The way perl does two dimensional data structures is via references.

In your example - `@points` isn't a 2d structure, it's a list of references - which is why if you print it you get:

```
print "@points";
```

Gives:

```
ARRAY(0x4a6dec) ARRAY(0x4a6fb4) ARRAY(0x12fef64)
```

So you need to dereference each of those elements. There's several ways to do this, but essentially `@{$reference}` is how it works.

There are a few ways of accomplishing the task, but essentially:

```
foreach my $group ( @points ) { 
    print join ("\n", @$group ),"\n"; 
}
```

For example - join is one iterate, foreach is another. (Note - `@$group` and `@{$group}` mean the same thing, so you don't need the braces. If you were trying to do @$group[1] you would need it, to disambiguate whether you were after `@{$group[1]}` or `@{$group}[1]`)

Or for another:

```
use feature qw ( say );
say for map { @$_ } @points;
```

This is making use of the fact that `map` is applying a transform to each element of `@points`, and that "transform" is simply "dereference and give me the elements".

Of course, then you have 'smashed flat' `@points` and not retained their mutual association.

Comment: This does it! I knew that I was making a mistake somewhere with references, however I did not realize that you have to explicitly dereference an array in order to then use and manipulate it. Thank you very much for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `@{ ... }` sigil to *dereference* your array references. This will give you a plain array that you can print directly or manipulate with the [`join`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/join.html) builtin to get better formatted output:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @points = ([34.2,17.5],[-64.1, 110.35],[54.8,77.1]);
print join(',', @$_), "\n" foreach my @points;
```

output:

```
34.2,17.5
-64.1,110.35
54.8,77.1
```

You should note that I placed parentheses around your definition of the `@points` array:

```
my @points = ([34.2,17.5],[-64.1, 110.35],[54.8,77.1]);
```

these parentheses are required due to how [lists are constructed in Perl](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Comma-Operator), without them present `@points` would only be assigned the final array reference of `[54.8,77.1]`

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. I was not familiar with the process of dereferencing and that is where I was getting stuck.

Answer (score 1):

You may use the [Data::Dumper](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Dumper) CPAN module, it's simple:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my @points = ( [34.2,17.5], [-64.1, 110.35], [54.8,77.1] );
$Data::Dumper::Terse = 1;
print Dumper(\@points), "\n";

#---> prints:
[
  [
    '34.2',
    '17.5'
  ],
  [
    '-64.1',
    '110.35'
  ],
  [
    '54.8',
    '77.1'
  ]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

One More solution for this, although I changed `@points` to `reference`.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $points = [[34.2,17.5],[-64.1, 110.35],[54.8,77.1]];

for(my $i = 0; $i<=6; $i++)
{
    print $points->[$i]->[0];
    print "\n";
    print $points->[$i]->[1];
    print "\n";
}
```